# How to start postgresql server with the socket at a different place?

Tags: postgresql, socket, openbsd

Good morning. The title says it, but let me precise it.

I am working with openbsd. The web server is chrooted in /var/www. So the good thing would be that postgresgl place its socket (and the lock, I assume) in the chroot, typically /var/www/tmp/…

If I change the option **unix_socket_directories** to /var/www/tmp, then the server will actually set the socket in /tmp (default behavior), then search for it in /var/www/tmp. That result in a crash, and the server cannot start effectivelly.

So how can I set the postgresql socket in /var/www/tmp ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the manual says you can list multiple directories for the socket directive

Answer (score 0):

You can try using what in linux is called 'bind mount', which I believe on bsd is called nullfs. This way you can mount /tmp on /var/www/tmp and have the same files visible on both places.

`mount -t nullfs /tmp /var/www/tmp`